# How to add multiple Publish Agent?

Tags: publishing, scheduled-tasks, automation

I'm trying to add multiple `PublishAgent` as below but it resolved to only one `PublishAgent` as visible in the `/ShowConfig.aspx`

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <scheduling>
      <!-- Agent to publish to web database periodically -->
      <agent name="web" type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent" method="Run" interval="00:15:10">
        <param desc="source database">master</param>
        <param desc="target database">web</param>
        <param desc="mode (full or smart or incremental)">incremental</param>
        <param desc="languages">en</param>
      </agent>

      <!-- Agent to publish to web database periodically -->
      <agent name="abc" type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent" method="Run" interval="00:15:20">
        <param desc="source database">master</param>
        <param desc="target database">abc</param>
        <param desc="mode (full or smart or incremental)">incremental</param>
        <param desc="languages">en</param>
      </agent>

      <!-- Agent to publish to web database periodically -->
      <agent name="pqr" type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent" method="Run" interval="00:15:30">
        <param desc="source database">master</param>
        <param desc="target database">pqr</param>
        <param desc="mode (full or smart or incremental)">incremental</param>
        <param desc="languages">en</param>
      </agent>

      <!-- Agent to publish to web database periodically -->
      <agent name="xyz" type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent" method="Run" interval="00:15:40">
        <param desc="source database">master</param>
        <param desc="target database">xyz</param>
        <param desc="mode (full or smart or incremental)">incremental</param>
        <param desc="languages">en</param>
      </agent>

      <!-- Agent to publish to web database periodically -->
      <agent name="def" type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent" method="Run" interval="00:15:50">
        <param desc="source database">master</param>
        <param desc="target database">def</param>
        <param desc="mode (full or smart or incremental)">incremental</param>
        <param desc="languages">en</param>
      </agent>

      <!-- Agent to publish to web database periodically -->
      <agent name="bac" type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent" method="Run" interval="00:15:60">
        <param desc="source database">master</param>
        <param desc="target database">bac</param>
        <param desc="mode (full or smart or incremental)">incremental</param>
        <param desc="languages">en</param>
      </agent>
    </scheduling>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

How to add multiple `PublishAgent` agent using patch config?

Comment: What you have is fine. Just remove the name="xxx" on each of them. You don't need that. Are you not seeing the publishes run?

Comment: The above config is correct, and **you do require** the `name="xyz"` attribute in order to make the element unique (otherwise they patch override each other). Make sure the config file is correctly deployed to IIS and double check the showconfig page.

Comment: I verified as well- copy/pasted your exact patch in a project and it's showing up properly.

Comment: Looks like it works now. I guess I has to recycle IIS or I had overlooked this somehow however now `/showconfig.aspx` shows the changes. Thanks everyone. :D